# Upgrading CQ5.6.1 to AEM 6.1, authentication issues

Tags: aem

I have been following the instructions on 
 
https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-1/deploy/upgrade.html

I reached "Once the upgrade is finished, the AEM homepage will be shown."

However, all I get is "an HTTP 503 status for all requests except for those under http:///system/console", exactly as described at the NOTE under this step.

The problem is that I always get this error, not only during the upgrade, but also **after the upgrade is finished!**

The error.log states:

```
11.11.2015 12:38:29.888 *ERROR* [qtp231586654-77] org.apache.sling.engine.impl.SlingHttpContext handleSecurity: AuthenticationSupport service missing. Cannot authenticate request.
11.11.2015 12:38:29.888 *ERROR* [qtp231586654-77] org.apache.sling.engine.impl.SlingHttpContext handleSecurity: Possible reason is missing Repository service. Check AuthenticationSupport dependencies.
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: @Stravos I had to reinstall CQ. Only solution i found...

Comment: I had the same problem, and the only solution was to reinstall. But it would be interesting to know why this happend. and if this happen again, then is reinstallation not a really good solution. I've already worked since half a year with aem 6.1 and then from one second to the other I get the error 503 and the server was death.

Answer (score 2):

We've encountered this once:
There were issues with diskspace (the disk was simply full), make sure you have an adequate amount of space available.

Comment: have you verified that all bundles are running?  Under http://yourhost:4502/system/console/bundles

Comment: It is also stated here https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1026290?start=0&tstart=0 that you might have corrupted lucene indices (see the last post)

Comment: Thank for the links @mish. I have rebuilt the indices. I have a few bundles that are just "installed", but when I press run, they don't start.. Any idea on how to force them to start?

Comment: This could be because of unmet dependencies, when you expand the bundles, do you see any packages marked in red? This could signify that those packages are not installed/available

Comment: For most of them (around 20) I don't get anything in red. For 2-3 I get something like: com.day.crx.core.ntlm -- Cannot be resolved but is not required

Comment: are you perhaps using ldap authentication? Because the way custom login modules are configured has changed since 5.6
see here: https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-1/deploy/upgrade.html and here: https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-1/administer/security/ldap-config.html

Answer (score 2):

There could be two possible reasons:

1. Some of the bundles are not active.
2. Lucene is corrupt and hence not able to start

Possible fix is:

1. Bring your bundles back to active, if it is not active.
2. Stop your instance. go to `crx-quickstart\repository\index` and delete index folder.

Restart the instance (This will regenerate Lucene indexes fully).

Answer (score 1):

Quick fix:

1. Stop the AEM instance.
2. Go to folder `crx-quickstart\repository\` remove folder **index**
3. Start the AEM.

Everything should working fine. (It's working for me)

Comment: This is only useful if you see index corruption errors in your log. Removing index folder will force the repopulation of index cache from your datastore. If your datastore is not accessible this step will not do anything and you will end up with an empty index folder. In your case the repository worked because your index cache was corrupted but that is not OP's case where repository was inaccessible.

Answer (score 0):

Check the permissions under `crx-quickstart\repository\` after you deleted the index.

Answer (score 0):

For me it had nothing to do with the segmentstore or the index or any unsatisfied bundles. Instead, it was the datastore.

The permissions for the datastore directory didn’t allow the user running aem to access it. The datastore directory is configured in `org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.plugins.blob.datastore.FileDataStore`.

This error really should reveal its root cause a little bit more easily. I’m sure it was somewhere in the logs, though…